# SQL Server: use Case statement for variable declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, case

**I have a dynamic procedure with the following input variables:**

```
@selection nvarchar(20),
@searchCategory nvarchar(100) = '',
@searchTerm nvarchar(256) = ''
```

The procedure in general works as intended - except for the following: 
If the searchCategory is "`dateRec`" then the searchTerm format would be a date and the corresponding column would be datetime whereas for everything else they are nvarchar.

Is there any way in SQL that I can use a Case or If statement or something else for the variable declaration to set the last variable as `@searchTerm datetime` if @searchCategory = "`dateRec`" and only for all other cases set it as `@searchTerm nvarchar(256)` as above ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you can't change the parameters of that stored procedure, then you could use two local variables having the right data type thus:

```
...
DECLARE @localSearchTermDT DATETIME,
    @localSearchTermCHR NVARCHAR(256);

IF @searchCategory = 'dateRec'
    SET @localSearchTermDT = CONVERT(DATETIME, @searchTerm, ...)
ELSE
    SET @localSearchTermCHR = @searchTerm;
```

Note: this solution will block parameter sniffing.

2) Another solution is to use CAST/CONVERT thus:

```
...
Column1DT = CASE WHEN @searchCategory = 'dateRec' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @searchTerm, ...) END
...
Column2CHR = CASE WHEN @searchCategory <> 'dateRec' THEN @searchTerm END
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an additional variable of type `datetime`, then use a `CASE`, `IF`, or sets of criteria in `WHERE` to
 pick which variable gets used.

```
@selection nvarchar(20),
@searchCategory nvarchar(100) = '',
@searchTerm nvarchar(256) = '',
@searchTerm2 datetime = ''
```